# Unable to locate package ros-groovy-desktop-full

Tags: ros, package, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My ubuntu linux is 12.04. And I want to install ROS, but when I followed the instruction in ros.org, in the step of "sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full", I got this problem "Unable to locate package ros-groovy-desktop-full". And I tried other version of ROS such as hydro and diamondback and other version of ubuntu such as 12.10, this problem can not be solved.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/139401/unable-to-locate-package-ros-groovy-desktop-full/) by [rosmichael](https://answers.ros.org/users/13231/rosmichael/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you checked if your ubuntu allows  "restricted," "universe," and "multiverse" ?
if not-easiest way is to download Synaptic Package Manager, run it and check settings in Settings->Repositories and in the first tab "Ubuntu Software" there is all wrote down.
than you have to add good repo for your ubuntu, as in tutorial and u should not forgot about

```
sudo apt-get update
```

than you can check if apt-get finds sth (find or just type `sudo apt-get install ros`- and press tab)

---

Originally posted by [BP](https://answers.ros.org/users/10951/bp/) with karma: 176 on 2014-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosmichael](https://answers.ros.org/users/13231/rosmichael/) on 2014-03-12**:
thanks solved by goagent